# where tag value of UIButton in interface builder is gone in xcode 5?

Tags: xcode5

I was just updated my xcode to xcode 5 , now i need to set the tag value of UIBUTTON in interface builder , but i can't see any tag textfield in xcode 5 , Please tell me where it is gone ?

Answer (score 25):

On the attribute pane, scroll down to View. Hover over it and you'll see on the right it shows Show. Click on it and it will expand and show you the Tag value.